# herança de template c++

Tags: c++, herança

Tenho as 3 classes a seguir e 2 erros de compilação somente na terceira classe, não consigo identificar o que seja.
os 2 erro:

- error: expected template-name before '<' token
- error: expected '{' before '<' token

os 2 erros são na linha do código: ***class Size3 : public Size2< Size3Type >{***

ou seja é na herança da classe Size2 na declaração da classe Size3, alguma sugestão pra corrigir isso?

```
class Size1{
    public:
        Size1(Size1Type width = 0){}
        ~Size1(){}

    public:
        Size1Type width;
};

template<class Size2Type>
class Size2 : public Size1<Size2Type>{
    public:
        Size2(Size2Type width = 0, Size2Type height = 0){}
        ~Size2(){}

    public:
        Size2Type height;
};

template<class Size3Type>
    class Size3 : public Size2<Size3Type>{
    public:
        Size3(Size3Type width = 0, Size3Type height = 0, Size3Type depth = 0){}
        ~Size3(){}

    public:
        Size3Type height;
};
```